# Show element pressing a button while hiding all other elements

Tags: javascript, css

I have 5 buttons and I want to show only one specific section per button while hiding all other sections. I have different elements with an id and class attributes.

The code for the button is:

```
document.getElementById('ID-name').classList.toggle('CLASS-name');
```

There must be a code I can use first which closes all other sections.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Currently you are not asking any question.

Comment: Please post the CSS you use for the sections (in order to show/hide them).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: close all sections first, then open the targeted one. Given that your "sections" have the IDs `ID-name1-5` and that `open` is your CSS class for opened sections and sections are closed when it's missing:

```js
function openSection(sectionID) {
    ['ID-name-1', 'ID-name-2', 'ID-name-3', 'ID-name-4', 'ID-name-5'].forEach(s -> document.getElementById(s).classList.remove('open'))
    document.getElementById(sectionID).classList.add('open')
}
```

Comment: didn't work or I made something wrong.
`function openSection(bestellungja) {
    ['bestellungja', 'bestellungnein', 'erstregistrierungja', 'erstregistrierungnein', 'arzteja'].forEach(s -> document.getElementById(s).classList.remove('bestellung-ja'))
    document.getElementById(bestellungja).classList.add('bestellung-ja')
}`

Comment: the version with sectionID didnt work either.... sry, I am a real noob

Comment: @user244972 please give more context / post the CSS you use (s.a.)